# Вызов сразу двух методов к одному объекту. Python

Tags: python, ооп

**Имеется:** строка `user_str = "  Привет как ДЕЛА? "`. Нужно убрать пробелы с двух сторон и убрать большой регистр букв.

**Вопрос:** можно ли сделать эту задачу так `user_str.strip().lower()`? Или нужно применить методы по очереди `user_str.strip()` и на следующей строке метод `lower()`? Первый вариант какой-то не очень красивый, по моему мнению.

Comment: можно первый, вполне нормальный вариант

Comment: @Alexandr, то-есть кроме эстетической красоты, использование первого метода не отличается от использования второго метода?

Comment: есть смысл разделять цепочки методов, чтобы они были более читаемые, в данном случае код предельно ясен и без разделения

Comment: @Alexandr, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень хочется, то можно использовать перенос строки внутри скобок:

```
user_str = (
    user_str
    .strip()
    .lower()
)
```

или

```
user_str = (user_str
            .strip()
            .lower()
            )
```

Но для всего пары методов нет большого смысла такое городить, можно записать в одну строчку. А вот при работе с sqlalchemy, где часто последовательно вызывается 10+ методов, такая запись в столбик используется часто.